# Application_Error not called when using Elmah.MVC

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, asp.net-mvc-5, elmah, elmah.mvc

I had some custom error handling code in `Application_Error`, which was doing some logging and then handing off to my `Error` controller action/view. I had a bizarre issue where **sometimes** - and only on my production server, not on my development machine - the error page would appear, but no error details were recorded in the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent several hours trying to figure this out, and it turns out that my error page was being invoked directly, without going through `Application_Error`!

I saw a throwaway comment on another SO post that implied that this might happen with the `HandleError` attribute - i.e. that it would look for a view called `Error`, and simply render that, bypassing `Application_Error`.

I was using Elmah.MVC, and so did not explicitly use the `HandleError` attribute, because Elmah does this for you. However, it turns out that Elmah also does the straight-to-error-view thing too, because when I renamed my view (and controller action) to something else, everything started working as expected.

Just posting this in case it helps someone else...